# I am unable to deploy a smart contract(Simple Storage) to hardhat programmatically

Tags: javascript, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

```js
const {ethers} = require("hardhat")

async function main(){
const SimpleStorageFactory =  await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage")  
console.log("Deploying,....")
const simpleStorage= SimpleStorageFactory.deploy()
await (await simpleStorage).deployed()
}
```

On this function , I am running into an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContractFactory')
```

Can someone tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining that ethers is not defined, check your package.json to see if you correct installed hardhat-ethers plugin.

https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/tree/master/packages/hardhat-ethers

Answer (score 1):

On the last line, I see two "await" which is not correct I think. I would create deploy script like this:

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const SimpleStorage = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage")  
  const simpleStorage= await SimpleStorage.deploy();
  await simpleStorage.deployed();
  console.log(`simple storage deployed: ${simpleStorage.address}` )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code snippet at the top of your hardhat.config.js file

```
    require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
```

solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628980/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-getcontractfactory-wh

Answer (score 0):

presuming the simple storage contract doesn't require any deploy time arguments

try this

```
const simpleStorageFactory =  await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage") 
const simpleStorage = await simpleStorageFactory.deploy()
await simpleStorage.deployed()
```